# where.exe does not find OpenSSL libs when %ProgramFiles% variable is used in the PATH environment variable

Tags: windows, 64-bit, 32-bit, path, environment-variables

I installed both 32bit and 64bit version of OpenSSL libs on Vista x64. The 32bit version was installed in `c:\Program Files (x86)\OpenSSL` and the 64bit version was installed in `c:\Program Files\OpenSSL`. Then I added the entry `%ProgramFiles%\OpenSSL` to the `PATH` environment variable. `%ProgramFiles%\OpenSSL` is expanded to `c:\Program Files (x86)\OpenSSL` for 32bit programs and it's expanded to `c:\Program Files\OpenSSL` for 64bit programs. The idea is to have 32bit programs use 32bit version of OpenSSL libs and 64bit programs use 64bit version. I wanted to check if this works by running 32bit cmd.exe and issuing `where ssleay32.dll` and then by running 64bit cmd.exe and issuing the same. However in both cases I get the error `INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).`
What's wrong?

This is a follow up to
[Different PATH environment variable for 32bit and 64bit Windows - is it possible?](https://superuser.com/questions/247614/)

Comment: What happens when you search for openssl.exe, rather than a dll? Also, have you tried another method, such as executing openssl.exe in cmd to see if it is the right one ? (You may use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see which openssl.exe version is executing). It may be that "where" does not work very well under your environment.

Comment: `where openssl.exe` finds the one in OpenVPN folder which is after OpenSSL one in the PATH.

Comment: I think you have proven very soundly that %ProgramFiles% does not work as expected in the PATH. Maybe [cmd -k](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) will work with the parameter of "set path=%path%;%ProgramFiles%\OpenSSL", or some other combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the 32bit .DLLs into the \Windows\SysWOW64 directory and the 64bit DLLs into the \Windows\system32 directory.

EDIT:

Maybe this helps:

> This is just an intelligent guess, but following some investigation I
>   believe I've found the problem:
>
> If the definition of an environment
>   variable var1 contains another
>   environment variable var2 and the name
>   of var1 is alphabetically less than
>   the name of var2 (i.e. strcmp(var1,
>   var2) < 0), then var2 won't get
>   expanded. This seems to be because
>   when Windows first sets up the
>   environment variables, they are
>   created in alphabetical order, so var2
>   does not exist until after var1 has
>   already been created (and so the
>   expansion can't be done).
>
> I believe this is a limitation in
>   Windows. Really some sort of
>   dependency check between the variables
>   should be carried out so that they are
>   created in the correct order.
>   Fortunately, there is a workaround.
>
> 1) Enable 'delayed variable expansion'
>   in the registry (see
>   http://batcheero.blogspot.com/2007/06/how-to-enabledelayedexpansion.html)
>
> 2) Change the '%' signs around var2 to
>   '!', e.g. "%var2%" becomes "!var2!"
>
> I've done some limited testing on
>   Windows 7 and this appears to fix the
>   problem.

It's from here: http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vistainstall/thread/48b23109-9fbc-47c5-a5d1-465773f94704

Comment: Why should I? My current setup should work. I'd like to know why it doesn't.

Comment: It doesn't work, thats why you should give it a try. I understand that it **should** work. I'm just trying to help. And windows is searching the above paths for .DLLs. If it works that way i wouldn't care why the other configuration isn't working. Maybe it's a bug or working as intended. We don't know... Obviously no one else does know or is willing to answer. Try it or leave it the way it is...

Comment: *If it works that way i wouldn't care why the other configuration isn't working.* I care :)

Comment: @Piotr Dobrogost I don't care about the bounty. If you give it to me or not doesn't matter to me. But i just found the stuff i edited into the post...

Comment: Setting delayed variable expansion in the registry makes output of `echo %path%` display paths with %ProgramFiles% being properly expanded. However, where.exe still doesn't handle such paths.

Answer (score 2):

It seems harrymc is right saying

> I think you have proven very soundly
>   that %ProgramFiles% does not work as
>   expected in the PATH.

The odd thing is I can't find any information on this problem using google...

The solution I went for is inspired by idea in Darokthar's answer;
I symlinked
`c:\windows\system32\OpenSSL-bin` to `c:\Program Files\OpenSSL\bin`
and
`c:\windows\SysWOW64\OpenSSL-bin` to `c:\Program Files (x86)\OpenSSL\bin`
and added `c:\windows\system32\OpenSSL-bin` to PATH.

Answer (score 1):

Root of the prob: the "alphabetic" nonsense in Windows (i.e. `envvar1` is not expanded within another `envvar2` if `envvar2` "comes first" alphabetically).

My workaround: forget about using `%ProgramFiles%` completely, even with delayed variable expansion.  Instead create another envvar, called `_ProgFiles` or similar: the leading underscore will mean that all other envvars following it alphabetically will use it as properly expanded ...

So your PATH will read `... ;%_ProgFiles%\OpenSSL;...` or something like this.