# Is there some way to universally address the default Program Files folder in Windows 7/2008 via .BAT file?

Tags: batch-file

I'd like to write a batch file, where some commands target items in the `Program Files` folder, that is naturally cross-compatible from Windows XP up to Windows 7 x64 and Server 2008 R2.  However, the folder name I'd need in the 64-bit systems is `Program Files (x86)`.

Is there a batch command that will allow me to detect the system architecture, and write an IF statement to use the appropriate folder?  Alternately, is there a universally-applicable environment variable that will point me to the right folder?  Or, would I have to set part of my script to look for the x86 folder and use it if present, only using the other folder if it's not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Different PATH environment variable for 32bit and 64bit Windows - is it possible?](http://superuser.com/questions/247614/different-path-environment-variable-for-32bit-and-64bit-windows-is-it-possible)

Answer (score 1):

I can't remember where I found this, but you are welcome to it. I modified it to check for 32 bit and 64 bit Windows 7. It should be fairly self explanatory.

```
@echo off

ver | find "2003" > nul
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto ver_2003

ver | find "XP" > nul
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto ver_xp

ver | find "2000" > nul
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto ver_2000

ver | find "NT" > nul
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto ver_nt

if not exist %SystemRoot%\system32\systeminfo.exe goto warnthenexit

systeminfo | find "OS Name" > %TEMP%\osname.txt
FOR /F "usebackq delims=: tokens=2" %%i IN (%TEMP%\osname.txt) DO set vers=%%i

echo %vers% | find "Windows 7" > nul
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto ver_7

echo %vers% | find "Windows Server 2008" > nul
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto ver_2008

echo %vers% | find "Windows Vista" > nul
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto ver_vista

goto warnthenexit

:ver_7

::Check if 32 or 64 bit
Set RegQry=HKLM\Hardware\Description\System\CentralProcessor\0
REG.exe Query %RegQry% > checkOS.txt
Find /i "x86" < CheckOS.txt > StringCheck.txt

    If %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (
        :Run Windows 7 32 bit specific commands here.
        Echo "This is 32 Bit Windows 7"
    ) ELSE (
        :Run Windows 7 64 bit specific commands here.
        Echo "This is 64 Bit Windows 7"
    )

goto exit

:ver_2008
:Run Windows Server 2008 specific commands here.
echo Windows Server 2008
goto exit

:ver_vista
:Run Windows Vista specific commands here.
echo Windows Vista
goto exit

:ver_2003
:Run Windows Server 2003 specific commands here.
echo Windows Server 2003
goto exit

:ver_xp
:Run Windows XP specific commands here.
echo Windows XP
goto exit

:ver_2000
:Run Windows 2000 specific commands here.
echo Windows 2000
goto exit

:ver_nt
:Run Windows NT specific commands here.
echo Windows NT
goto exit

:warnthenexit
echo Machine undetermined.

:exit
```

Comment: Wow.  That's a *lot* longer and more detailed than what I was looking for, but *nice*!

Answer (score 1):

You can just check if ProgramFiles(x86) is empty or not. As long as no user or program set it manually.

```
@ECHO OFF

IF "%ProgramFiles(x86)%"=="" GOTO 64 ELSE goto 86

:64
ECHO %ProgramFiles(x86)%

GOTO Quit

:86
ECHO %ProgramFiles%

GOTO Quit

:Quit
PAUSE
```

Alternatively, you could check the variable PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE - if it's a 32-bit system it should be "x86", if it's a x86-64 it should be "AMD64", if it's an Itanium CPU it should be "IA64". I haven't tested the Itanium one, though. And I'm not sure what these would say in the case of a 32-bit Windows system being installed on a x86-64 machine.

These were checked/tested on Windows 7, and should work on Vista. Windows XP 64-bit has always been dodgy, though, so it might not work there.

Comment: 32-bit Windows on a 64-bit machine reports x86.  I had a 64-bit system that reported AMD64, but I'm pretty sure it had an Intel processor.

Comment: @Iszi AMD64 is how Windows refers to x86-64 processors - both AMD and Intel ones. IA64 is a completely different architecture, and does not really apply since it does not support 32-bit programs.